# iphone xcode - different levels of drill down in tab bar controller - nav controller - table view

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have this type of data categories:

today news -> news item

jobs news -> news item

general news -> sub category news -> news item

So i have followed the very good tutorial 'Building an iPhone App Combining Tab Bar, Navigation and Tab' http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw and all is good with the 1st two 'todays news' and 'jobs news' but can't figure out the best method for implementing the sub category table view?

Do i use the same table view but reload it with the sub categories then some how work out when one is click that it's a sub category or is there a better method?

This is how i'm set up in Main Window.Xib

```
- Tab Bar Controller
- -Navigation Controller (today)
- - - Table View (list of today news)
- -Navigation Controller (jobs)
- - - Table View (list of jobs news)
- -Navigation Controller (general)
- - - Table View (general sub cat) // how to implement this Table View
- - - - Table View (list of sub cat news)
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it in exactly the same way as you two previous lists of news, but have the `UITableViewDelegate` select method push the sub category table view onto the navigation controller.

Comment: Would I have to create the table view in interface builder and classes or can I manage it in the same file?

Comment: can you list some steps to say how you would do it for jobs in my example?